# Delete JSON format in Rails controller and views

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

In my rails app I scaffolded a lot of models. During the scaffold specific views only for json (e.g. show.json.jbuilder) and "formt.json { render xyz}" in the controller were created. I do not understand why I should need and use them. Can I just delete the json views and the format.json lines in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

Scaffolding is just a template.  It creates controllers, views and tests for the most common situations.

If you are not using javascript, and never access the controllers outside of the html views, then yes, it is not only acceptable to delete the unused view files, and remove the render lines of the controllers, but it also considered a "best practice".  No need to have code lying around that you aren't using.

This is especially true when creating a project that starts small but grows much larger, in a year, you won't remember which files are used and which aren't, so it will take a mini-research project just to clean up your code.  Best to do it as you go.

If you are not using javascript yet, but you plan to include it in the coming days/weeks as you build out your app, you might leave those lines and files for a bit, because they'll be useful later as guides.